# AWS : execute script from ec2-user user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 userdata script which looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
yum -y install python3
yum -y install python3-pip
pip3 install boto3
pip3 install pandas
aws s3 cp s3://<bucket name>/script.py /home/ec2-user/script.py
chown ec2-user:ec2-user /home/ec2-user/script.py
echo "@reboot /home/ec2-user/script.py">> /var/spool/cron/ec2-user
```

All worked well, it added an entry in ec2-user crontab when EC2 instance is created.

**However**, when I stopped and started the instance, this crontab entry did not get executed - probably because it starts with root user, not ec2-user?

I wanted to execute ec2-user crontab entry on startup. *I can not have entries in root user's crontab going forward.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a crontab entry for a user

```
  crontab -u ec2-user /home/ec2-user/script.py
```

-u Specifies the user whose crontab is to be viewed or modified. If this option is not given, crontab opens the crontab of the user who ran crontab.

Say your script needs to be run only after 5 minutes. For example: reboot + 5mintues. The syntax is as follows:

```
@reboot sleep 300 && /home/ec2-user/script.py
```

Comment: did'nt get you , where to add this , my script has to run on every reboot  , user data script will run only once ( at the time of creation )

Comment: [ec2 userdata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)  is a method of provisioning the machine for some basic stuff. In this case it will schedule the cron for you for a the specific user.